# Woocommerce hook from Order processing to Order Cancelled but before order status changed to cancelled?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook, orders

in Woocommerce, is there any way to catch an order cancellation from processing before the order status is changed to its final state (cancelled)?

I tried `woocommerce_order_status_changed` and `woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_cancelled` hooks with negative priorities and in that hooks the order is in its final state (cancelled) yet.

Comment: What issue does this present? What do you actually need to _achieve_, that you can't do when the order _is_ in that state already?

Comment: It depends on the code that is making that status change and where is that code used (context). Try to clarify your question, please.

Comment: when the order is being cancelled I need to start a dokan refund workflow that can not be started when the order is cancelled but yes if processing. So i need to run my code just before order cancelled. When it is in processing state yet.

Comment: There is refund button with refund status for orders.

Comment: hello Snuffy. are you talking about a plugin?